# How do I know whether it is signed hexadecimal or unsignedhexadecimal?

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, unsigned, signed

In assembly Language, I can't tell if hexadecimal is signed or unsigned

```
mov al, 83h
mov al, 083h
```

Maybe I think that the 0 in front of the hexadecimal means something
Please help and thank you in advance

Comment: You can't tell, because there is no difference.

Comment: bits are bits, they are irrelevant until used and only relevant for that one moment then become irrelevant again.  Bits in a register only become an address when they are used to read/write something, but when they are part of an add operation (to adjust the pointer) they are not an address just an operand.

Comment: it is true that in C if you preceed a number by zero it becomes octal 0123 != 123, but those are hex numbers and assembly language

Comment: The 0 means nothing (unlike `C`), except you sometimes signalize the assembler that this is a number and not a label when it begins with a character ('A'..'F').

Comment: If it's a _signed_ or an _unsigned_ `int` solely depends on how you are using it.

Comment: If your intent is use a byte (you are showing `al`) as a signed number than the Most Significant Bit (MSB) will be set. As others noted there is no notion of signed unsigned but how you care to interpret it. BTW: The MSB notion also works with 16, 32, 64 bit registers/values.

Comment: The `083h` is in binary `1000 0011`, and that's what the 8 bits of `AL` will be set to. Whether you treat those bits as +131, or -125, or separate bit flags, or part of sound sample, or colour brightness, or text character, or anything else.... depends on the following code, how it does use the value in `AL`. (that means you can replace `mov al,83h` also with `mov al,-125` and you will get the identical machine code + functionality, even if the following code is treating the `AL` as unsigned integer).